# How to query a list that have due dates which is overdue? (Activerecord)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord

I have a table which contains a list of contracts and I want to list all contracts which it's due date is **overdue**. **For example, the due date for the contract is 4 October and today's date is 5 October**, so this contract is overdue. So, I figure out that I can do it like this:

```
@contract_dues_over = ContractDue.where(Date.today > :due_date )
```

But somehow this query is wrong as it didn't give me the result that I want.
So how should I do it actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the query,

```
@contract_dues_over = ContractDue.where("due_date < ?", Date.today)
```

Edited: You need to reverse the `>` to `<`

Comment: Nope, this is not what I am looking for. I want the list which its date is overdue. So i have to compare if (date today > due_date). But i just cannot find the perfect solution

Comment: @ryzalyusoff Please try now, I have edited my answer, it should be less than (<) the `Date.today`.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work

```
@contract_dues_over = ContractDue.where("due_date < ?", Date.today)
```

Comment: I have tried this and the result is wrong. I want the list, which it's date is overdue. For example, if the contract's due date is 4 October and today's date is 5 October then this contract is considered as overdue.

Comment: @ryzalyusoff Try `@contract_dues_over = ContractDue.where("due_date < ?", Date.today)`